# Can I Have Redux-Saga and Redux-Thunk Working Together?

Tags: redux, redux-thunk, redux-saga

I was working with `redux-saga` but I'm with a problem: the `redux-auth-wrapper` needs the `redux-thunk` to do the redirects, so I simply added the thunk in my store:

```js
import {createStore, compose, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import {routerMiddleware} from 'react-router-redux';
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import createSagaMiddleware, {END} from 'redux-saga';
import sagas from '../sagas';
import reduxImmutableStateInvariant from 'redux-immutable-state-invariant';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import _ from 'lodash';
import {loadState, saveState} from '../connectivity/localStorage';

const persistedState = loadState();

const routerMw = routerMiddleware(browserHistory);
const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

function configureStoreProd() {
  const middlewares = [
    // Add other middleware on this line...

    routerMw,
    sagaMiddleware,
    thunk    
  ];

  const store = createStore(rootReducer, persistedState, compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
    )
  );

  store.subscribe(_.throttle(() => {
    saveState({
      auth: store.getState().auth
    });
  }, 1000));

  sagaMiddleware.run(sagas);
  store.close = () => store.dispatch(END);

  return store;
}

function configureStoreDev() {
  const middlewares = [
    // Add other middleware on this line...

    // Redux middleware that spits an error on you when you try to mutate your state either inside a dispatch or between dispatches.
    reduxImmutableStateInvariant(),

    routerMw,
    sagaMiddleware,
    loggerMiddleware,
    thunk
  ];

  const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose; // add support for Redux dev tools
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, persistedState, composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
    )
  );

  store.subscribe(_.throttle(() => {
    saveState({
      auth: store.getState().auth
    });
  }, 1000));

  if (module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
      const nextReducer = require('../reducers').default; // eslint-disable-line global-require
      store.replaceReducer(nextReducer);
    });
  }

  sagaMiddleware.run(sagas);
  store.close = () => store.dispatch(END);

  return store;
}

const configureStore = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? configureStoreProd : configureStoreDev;

export default configureStore;
```

This way works nice without errors, but I'm new in react and I don't know if have problem with `redux-saga` and `redux-thunk` working together...

Someone can help me?

Comment: No worry, No conflict. Indeed,  `redux-thunk` will intervenes only when the action is a function not a literal object. 
There shouldn't be any conflicts between using redux-thunk in conjunction with redux-saga.

Answer (score 18):

No problems to have both. Sagas are just background checkers who react to some actions while thunk let's you have more interesting action creators.

While thunk will act more like synced code, sagas will do it's job in a background.

Both extensions do not change how actions are flying around. Actions still, in the end, are just bare objects like w/o thunk or w/o sagas.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, of course you can use both redux-saga and redux-thunk in this way,

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'

import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import logger from 'redux-logger'

import rootSagas from './sagas'
import rootReducer from './reducers'

const saga = createSagaMiddleware()

const middleWares = [saga, thunk]

export const store = createStore(
 rootReducer,
 applyMiddleware(...middleWares)
)

saga.run(rootSagas)
```